# In Just Cause 2, when does Autosaving occur?

Tags: just-cause-2

When you die or load your game in Just Cause 2, you have to continue from the last autosave.  But it's not quite clear what exactly causes the autosave to occur other than checkpoints and completing areas.

Does autosaving occur after you clear part of a town, or can that progress be lost if you die?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've noticed auto-saving occur when:

- You die, generally, in the world. This excludes Faction/Agency missions.
- You 100% a location.
- You reach a checkpoint in a Faction/Agency mission.
- You complete a Faction/Agency mission.
- You collect a Faction item.

I've manually saved all of maybe 5 times in my game (mind you, this is on the *xbox 360*, YMMV on other systems). When you die, your current destruction/completion process is saved as-is, so if you made 78% of completion in a given location before dying, when you head back it will still be at 78%.

Comment: I also find it hilarious that they give you nearly 20 save slots for saving in, if I weren't new to the game I never would have saved the game manually, ever.

Comment: Cool, that's what was confusing me, they use a lot of bad terminology.

Comment: I noticed it doesn't save when you die if you are on a mission.

Comment: Correct, it saves at the checkpoints, and you do lose progress from checkpoint -> death, hence why you "continue from checkpoint" :).